# Convert multiple rows to columns but as one rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do i achieve achieve all this records under one row since every employee has one of each NHIF, NSSF and KRA number?

[image]

Below is the query i used but the all appear separate rows.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       hrmemployeehdr.employeeslno,
       hrmemployeehdr.employeecode,
       hrmemployeehdr.employeefirstname,
       hrmemployeehdr.employeemiddlename,
       hrmemployeehdr.employeelastname,
       hrmDesignationHdr.DesignationName,
       hrmemployeehdr.DateOfBirth,
       hrmemployeehdr.DateOfJoin,
       hlocationhdr.locationname,
       hrmEmployeeIdentityDtl.IDProofReferenceNo AS [National ID],
       (CASE
             WHEN hrmEmployeeDeductionSettingsDtl.DeductionCode = 1 THEN hrmEmployeeDeductionSettingsDtl.EmployeeRegID
             ELSE ''
        END) AS NHIF,
       (CASE
             WHEN hrmEmployeeDeductionSettingsDtl.DeductionCode = 2 THEN hrmEmployeeDeductionSettingsDtl.EmployeeRegID
             ELSE ''
        END) AS NSSF,
       (CASE
             WHEN hrmEmployeeDeductionSettingsDtl.DeductionCode = 3 THEN hrmEmployeeDeductionSettingsDtl.EmployeeRegID
             ELSE ''
        END) AS KRA,
       hrmemployeestatusdtl.Email AS [Employee Email],
       huser.email AS [User Account Email],
       hrmEmployeeGradeHdr.GradeName,
       hDepartment.DepartmentName
FROM hrmemployeehdr
     JOIN hrmemployeestatusdtl ON hrmemployeestatusdtl.employeeslno = hrmemployeehdr.employeeslno
     JOIN hdivision ON hdivision.divisioncode = hrmemployeestatusdtl.divisioncode
     JOIN hlocationhdr ON hlocationhdr.locationcode = hrmemployeestatusdtl.workinglocationcode
     JOIN hDepartment ON hDepartment.DepartmentCode = hrmemployeestatusdtl.DepartmentCode
     JOIN hrmDesignationHdr ON hrmDesignationHdr.DesignationCode = hrmemployeestatusdtl.DesignationCode
     JOIN hrmEmployeeCategoryHdr ON hrmEmployeeCategoryHdr.CategoryCode = hrmemployeestatusdtl.CategoryCode
     JOIN hrmEmployeeGradeHdr ON hrmEmployeeGradeHdr.GradeCode = hrmemployeestatusdtl.GradeCode
     LEFT JOIN huser ON huser.employeeslno = hrmemployeehdr.employeeslno
     JOIN hMasterValue ON hMasterValue.MasterValueID = hrmemployeestatusdtl.MasterValue_EmploymentStatusID
     JOIN hrmEmployeeIdentityDtl ON hrmEmployeeIdentityDtl.EmployeeSlno = hrmemployeehdr.EmployeeSlno
     INNER JOIN hMasterValue a ON a.MasterValueID = hrmEmployeeIdentityDtl.MasterValue_IDProofTypeID
     INNER JOIN hrmEmployeeDeductionSettingsDtl ON hrmEmployeeDeductionSettingsDtl.EmployeeSlno = hrmemployeehdr.EmployeeSlno
     LEFT JOIN hrmDeductionHdr ON hrmDeductionHdr.DeductionCode = hrmEmployeeDeductionSettingsDtl.DeductionCode
WHERE hrmemployeestatusdtl.employeeslno NOT IN (SELECT hrmemploymentstoppageandtermination.employeeslno
                                                FROM hrmemploymentstoppageandtermination)
  AND hrmEmployeeIdentityDtl.MasterValue_IDProofTypeID = 2741005
--and hrmemployeestatusdtl.email = huser.email 
--and huser.isemployee = 1
-- select * from huser
ORDER BY employeefirstname ASC;
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` with that many columns in the `SELECT` smells like you have a problem with your `JOIN`s.

Comment: Okay...How can i make this better. I have several tables i'm pulling this data from

Comment: Definitely seems like your `JOIN`s are wrong. Why are you even `JOIN`ing to half of these tables? For example you `LEFT JOIN` to `hrmDeductionHdr` but you don't reference it *once* outside of said `JOIN`. `hdivision` is literally just `JOIN`ed to, so why not an `EXISTS`? Same for `hrmEmployeeCategoryHdr`. `hMasterValue` you `JOIN` to *twice* and never use... *Why*?

Comment: Something smells. Your case expressions all use the same logic and "output" the same column, yet the KRA value is different from the other two for what seems to be the same employee.

Comment: There three number NHIF, NSSF and KRA but belong to one employee. Every employee has these three numbers

Comment: You miss the point. If those three expressions ALL return the same column (EmployeeRegID), then every non-blank value in your output should have the same value for the same employeeslno.

Comment: How can i go about it because i need all the three numbers in one row for each employee

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation on the detail table to condense all those rows into one for each employee. Something like:

```
with edet as (select employeeslno, 
    max(CASE DeductionCode when 1 THEN EmployeeRegID ELSE '' END) AS NHIF,
    max(CASE DeductionCode when 2 THEN EmployeeRegID ELSE '' END) AS NSSF,
    max(CASE DeductionCode when 3 THEN EmployeeRegID ELSE '' END) AS KRA 
from dbo.hrmEmployeeDeductionSettingsDtl
group by employeeslno)

select emp.employeeslno, ..., 
   edet.NHIF, edet.NSSF, edet.KRA, ...  
from dbo.hrmemployeehdr as emp 
inner join edet on emp.employeeslno = edet.employeeslno
... 
order by ... 
;
```

Notice the formatting changes that HELP everyone read and understand the code as well as the good habits of using aliases, schema-qualified table names, statement terminator, etc. As already mentioned, the other joins might be contributing to the problem - but this addresses the 1:3 relationship between the header and detail table.